# Re-assign column values in a pandas df

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, assign

This question is related to rostering or staffing. I'm trying to assign various jobs to individuals (employees). Using the `df` below,

```
`[Person]` = Individuals (employees)
`[Area]` and `[Place]` = unique jobs
`[On]` = How many unique jobs are occurring at each point in time
```

So `[Area]` and `[Place]` together will make up `unique` values that are different jobs. These values will be assigned to individuals with the overall aim to use the least amount of individuals possible. The most unique values `assigned` to any one individual is 3. `[On]` displays how many current `unique` values for `[Place]` and `[Area]` are occurring. So this provides a concrete guide on how many individuals I need. For example,

```
1-3 unique values occurring = 1 individual
4-6 unique values occurring = 2 individuals
7-9 unique values occurring = 3 individuals etc
```

**Question:**
Where the amount of `unique` values in `[Area]` and `[Place]` is greater than 3 is causing me trouble. I can't do a `groupby` where I `assign` the first `3 unique values` to `individual 1` and the next 3 `unique` values to `individual 2` etc. I want to group unique values in `[Area]` and `[Place]` by `[Area]`. So look to `assign` same values in `[Area]` to an individual (up to 3). Then, if there are *leftover* values (<3), they should be combined to make a group of 3, where possible.

The way I envisage this working is: *see into the future* by an `hour`. For each new `row` of values the `script` should see how many values will be `[On]`(this provides an indication of how many total individuals are required). Where `unique` values are >3, they should be `assigned` by `grouping` the same value in `[Area]`. If there are *leftover* values they should be combined anyhow to make up to a group of 3.

Putting that into a step by step process:

1) Use the `[On]` `Column` to determine how many individuals are required by looking *into the future* for an `hour`

2) Where there are more than 3 `unique` values occurring assign the identical values in `[Area]` first.

3) If there are any *leftover* values then look to combine anyway possible.

For the `df` below, there are 9 `unique` values occurring for `[Place]` and `[Area]` with an `hour`. So we should have 3 individuals `assigned`. When `unique` values >3 it should be assigned by `[Area]` and seeing if the same value occurs. The *leftover* values should be combined with other individuals that have less than 3 `unique` values.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

d = ({
    'Time' : ['8:03:00','8:17:00','8:20:00','8:28:00','8:35:00','08:40:00','08:42:00','08:45:00','08:50:00'],                 
    'Place' : ['House 1','House 2','House 3','House 4','House 5','House 1','House 2','House 3','House 2'],                 
    'Area' : ['A','B','C','D','E','D','E','F','G'],     
    'On' : ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'], 
    'Person' : ['Person 1','Person 2','Person 3','Person 4','Person 5','Person 4','Person 5','Person 6','Person 7'],   
     })

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

This is my attempt:

```
def reduce_df(df):
    values = df['Area'] + df['Place']
    df1 = df.loc[~values.duplicated(),:] # ignore duplicate values for this part..
    person_count = df1.groupby('Person')['Person'].agg('count')
    leftover_count = person_count[person_count < 3] # the 'leftovers'

    # try merging pairs together
    nleft = leftover_count.shape[0]
    to_try = np.arange(nleft - 1)
    to_merge = (leftover_count.values[to_try] + 
                leftover_count.values[to_try + 1]) <= 3
    to_merge[1:] = to_merge[1:] & ~to_merge[:-1]
    to_merge = to_try[to_merge]
    merge_dict = dict(zip(leftover_count.index.values[to_merge+1], 
                leftover_count.index.values[to_merge]))
    def change_person(p):
        if p in merge_dict.keys():
            return merge_dict[p]
        return p
    reduced_df = df.copy()
    # update df with the merges you found
    reduced_df['Person'] = reduced_df['Person'].apply(change_person)
    return reduced_df

df1 = (reduce_df(reduce_df(df)))
```

This is the Output:

```
       Time    Place Area On    Person
0   8:03:00  House 1    A  1  Person 1
1   8:17:00  House 2    B  2  Person 1
2   8:20:00  House 3    C  3  Person 1
3   8:28:00  House 4    D  4  Person 4
4   8:35:00  House 5    E  5  Person 5
5   8:40:00  House 1    D  6  Person 4
6   8:42:00  House 2    E  7  Person 5
7   8:45:00  House 3    F  8  Person 5
8   8:50:00  House 2    G  9  Person 7
```

This is my Intended Output:

```
       Time    Place Area On    Person
0   8:03:00  House 1    A  1  Person 1
1   8:17:00  House 2    B  2  Person 1
2   8:20:00  House 3    C  3  Person 1
3   8:28:00  House 4    D  4  Person 2
4   8:35:00  House 5    E  5  Person 3
5   8:40:00  House 6    D  6  Person 2
6   8:42:00  House 2    E  7  Person 3
7   8:45:00  House 3    F  8  Person 2
8   8:50:00  House 2    G  9  Person 3
```

Description on how I want to get this output:

```
Index 0: One `unique` value occurring. So `assign` to individual 1
Index 1: Two `unique` values occurring. So `assign` to individual 1
Index 2: Three `unique` values occurring. So `assign` to individual 1
Index 3: Four `unique` values on. So `assign` to individual 2
Index 4: Five `unique` values on. This one is a bit tricky and hard to conceptualise. But there is another `E` within an `hour`. So `assign` to a new individual so it can be combined with the other `E`
Index 5: Six `unique` values on. Should be `assigned` with the other `D`. So individual 2
Index 6: Seven `unique` values on. Should be `assigned` with other `E`. So individual 3
Index 7: Eight `unique` values on. New value in `[Area]`, which is a _leftover_. `Assign` to either individual 2 or 3
Index 8: Nine `unique` values on. New value in `[Area]`, which is a _leftover_. `Assign` to either individual 2 or 3
```

**Example No2:**

```
d = ({
    'Time' : ['8:03:00','8:17:00','8:20:00','8:28:00','8:35:00','8:40:00','8:42:00','8:45:00','8:50:00'],                 
    'Place' : ['House 1','House 2','House 3','House 1','House 2','House 3','House 1','House 2','House 3'],                 
    'Area' : ['X','X','X','X','X','X','X','X','X'],     
    'On' : ['1','2','3','3','3','3','3','3','3'], 
    'Person' : ['Person 1','Person 1','Person 1','Person 1','Person 1','Person 1','Person 1','Person 1','Person 1'],   
    })

    df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

I am getting an error:

```
 IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 1
```

On this line:

```
df.loc[:,'Person'] = df['Person'].unique()[assignedPeople]
```

However, if I change the Person to 1,2,3 repeating, it returns the following:

```
'Person' : ['Person 1','Person 2','Person 3','Person 1','Person 2','Person 3','Person 1','Person 2','Person 3'], 

      Time    Place Area On    Person
0  8:03:00  House 1    X  1  Person 1
1  8:17:00  House 2    X  2  Person 1
2  8:20:00  House 3    X  3  Person 1
3  8:28:00  House 1    X  3  Person 2
4  8:35:00  House 2    X  3  Person 2
5  8:40:00  House 3    X  3  Person 2
6  8:42:00  House 1    X  3  Person 3
7  8:45:00  House 2    X  3  Person 3
8  8:50:00  House 3    X  3  Person 3
```

Intended Output:

```
      Time    Place Area On    Person
0  8:03:00  House 1    X  1  Person 1
1  8:17:00  House 2    X  2  Person 1
2  8:20:00  House 3    X  3  Person 1
3  8:28:00  House 1    X  3  Person 1
4  8:35:00  House 2    X  3  Person 1
5  8:40:00  House 3    X  3  Person 1
6  8:42:00  House 1    X  3  Person 1
7  8:45:00  House 2    X  3  Person 1
8  8:50:00  House 3    X  3  Person 1
```

The main takeaway from Example 2 is:

```
1) There are <3 unique values on so assign to individual 1
```

Comment: I am confused about the desired output, why is Person 4 not part of your desired output? I think the constraints of the problem aren't super clear

Comment: Because we should only use 3 individuals as there are 9 unique values.

Comment: @PeterJames123 Your output looks good to me. You have 3 individuals in total as you needed.(Person1, Person2 and Person4). Why you can't use this output? If order of the person is important you can check the order and see Person3 is missing then you can replace Person4 by Person3 and s on....

Comment: @jimmy. I haven't got the logic right. If I change the input data it doesn't assign the way I'm hoping it would.

Comment: To rephrase the problem, in a nutshell you want to 1) find the number *n* of values assigned to a place/area at any point in time *t*, 2) for any combination of place/area and time *t* with *n > 1* allocate a person *p* to the *first 3 values, ordered by time*, 3) for any remaining values, group by place/area and allocate a person by the same rules. Correct? It might help if you explain the actual scenario (in "business terms")

Comment: @miraculixx. I can provide a high level overview of the application if you'd like. In a nutshell though. 1) For each point in time, determine how many _values_ of `Place/Area` are occurring within an `hour`. 2) If < 3 assign to individual 1. If >3 assign to individuals by group-by in `Area`. 3) For _leftover_ values assign to any individual.

Comment: In your question you say that the values' uniqueness depend on `Hour` and `Area`. At the same time you say that your input `d` has 9 unique values "occuring within the hour" even though it is 9 values (observations) split into multiple hours and 7 unique areas? I don't follow. There are also many different explanations in your question (and here in the comment section). I think it would be beneficial for you to review them and choose one.

Comment: I'm also having a hard time understanding problem. I think it might help if you gave some context. What does each row of the data represent? What are the places, and who are the people? Is this about assigning staff to resources?

Comment: I'm up for the bounty, but there's no way I can understand what you need. Don't try to explain what you think is good. Just give input, output and explain what exactly do you need, even if it's difficult. Your example input is also labeled as `Out`. You make it look like it doesn't matter what `Person no` is in `input` as long as `output` looks like what you need. I'm lost but I'd really like to help you. Where did the values in `Output intended` come from?

Comment: @user3471881, the unique values are between Place and Area? I'm not sure how you got hour? Sorry about the tiestamps. They're fixed now. There are 9 unique values between Place and Area. You need to take those two columns together

Comment: @grge. That is exactly what I'm trying to do.

Comment: @Tom Wojcik, can we take this to a chat?

Comment: I don't doubt that I (and others) misunderstood your criteria, but maybe that is indicative of your description being unclear? I would take @TomWojcik:s advice and restructure your question. Focus on 1) input and 2) expected output. You now show multiple inputs (3, from my count) which confuses things even more. Try to show one input and one output that represent your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Update

[There's a live version of this answer online that you can try for yourself.](https://repl.it/@telamonian/allocatePeople)

Here's an answer in the form of the `allocatePeople` function. It's based around precomputing all of the indices where the areas repeat within an hour:

```
from collections import Counter
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def getAssignedPeople(df, areasPerPerson):
    areas = df['Area'].values
    places = df['Place'].values
    times = pd.to_datetime(df['Time']).values
    maxPerson = np.ceil(areas.size / float(areasPerPerson)) - 1
    assignmentCount = Counter()
    assignedPeople = []
    assignedPlaces = {}
    heldPeople = {}
    heldAreas = {}
    holdAvailable = True
    person = 0

    # search for repeated areas. Mark them if the next repeat occurs within an hour
    ixrep = np.argmax(np.triu(areas.reshape(-1, 1)==areas, k=1), axis=1)
    holds = np.zeros(areas.size, dtype=bool)
    holds[ixrep.nonzero()] = (times[ixrep[ixrep.nonzero()]] - times[ixrep.nonzero()]) < np.timedelta64(1, 'h')

    for area,place,hold in zip(areas, places, holds):
        if (area, place) in assignedPlaces:
            # this unique (area, place) has already been assigned to someone
            assignedPeople.append(assignedPlaces[(area, place)])
            continue

        if assignmentCount[person] >= areasPerPerson:
            # the current person is already assigned to enough areas, move on to the next
            a = heldPeople.pop(person, None)
            heldAreas.pop(a, None)
            person += 1

        if area in heldAreas:
            # assign to the person held in this area
            p = heldAreas.pop(area)
            heldPeople.pop(p)
        else:
            # get the first non-held person. If we need to hold in this area, 
            # also make sure the person has at least 2 free assignment slots,
            # though if it's the last person assign to them anyway 
            p = person
            while p in heldPeople or (hold and holdAvailable and (areasPerPerson - assignmentCount[p] < 2)) and not p==maxPerson:
                p += 1

        assignmentCount.update([p])
        assignedPlaces[(area, place)] = p
        assignedPeople.append(p)

        if hold:
            if p==maxPerson:
                # mark that there are no more people available to perform holds
                holdAvailable = False

            # this area recurrs in an hour, mark that the person should be held here
            heldPeople[p] = area
            heldAreas[area] = p

    return assignedPeople

def allocatePeople(df, areasPerPerson=3):
    assignedPeople = getAssignedPeople(df, areasPerPerson=areasPerPerson)
    df = df.copy()
    df.loc[:,'Person'] = df['Person'].unique()[assignedPeople]
    return df
```

Note the use of `df['Person'].unique()` in `allocatePeople`. That handles the case where people are repeated in the input. It is assumed that the order of people in the input is the desired order in which those people should be assigned.

I tested `allocatePeople` against the OP's example input (`example1` and `example2`) and also against a couple of edge cases I came up with that I think(?) match the OP's desired algorithm:

```
ds = dict(
example1 = ({
    'Time' : ['8:03:00','8:17:00','8:20:00','8:28:00','8:35:00','08:40:00','08:42:00','08:45:00','08:50:00'],                 
    'Place' : ['House 1','House 2','House 3','House 4','House 5','House 1','House 2','House 3','House 2'],                 
    'Area' : ['A','B','C','D','E','D','E','F','G'],     
    'On' : ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'], 
    'Person' : ['Person 1','Person 2','Person 3','Person 4','Person 5','Person 4','Person 5','Person 6','Person 7'],   
    }),
example2 = ({
    'Time' : ['8:03:00','8:17:00','8:20:00','8:28:00','8:35:00','8:40:00','8:42:00','8:45:00','8:50:00'],                 
    'Place' : ['House 1','House 2','House 3','House 1','House 2','House 3','House 1','House 2','House 3'],                 
    'Area' : ['X','X','X','X','X','X','X','X','X'],     
    'On' : ['1','2','3','3','3','3','3','3','3'], 
    'Person' : ['Person 1','Person 1','Person 1','Person 1','Person 1','Person 1','Person 1','Person 1','Person 1'],   
    }),

long_repeats = ({
    'Time' : ['8:03:00','8:17:00','8:20:00','8:25:00','8:30:00','8:31:00','8:35:00','8:45:00','8:50:00'],                 
    'Place' : ['House 1','House 2','House 3','House 4','House 1','House 1','House 2','House 3','House 2'],                 
    'Area' : ['A','A','A','A','B','C','C','C','B'],  
    'Person' : ['Person 1','Person 1','Person 1','Person 2','Person 3','Person 4','Person 4','Person 4','Person 3'],   
    'On' : ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'],                      
    }),
many_repeats = ({
    'Time' : ['8:03:00','8:17:00','8:20:00','8:28:00','8:35:00','08:40:00','08:42:00','08:45:00','08:50:00'],                 
    'Place' : ['House 1','House 2','House 3','House 4','House 1','House 1','House 2','House 1','House 2'],                 
    'Area' : ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'D', 'E', 'E', 'F', 'F'],     
    'On' : ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'], 
    'Person' : ['Person 1','Person 1','Person 1','Person 2','Person 3','Person 4','Person 3','Person 5','Person 6'],   
    }),
large_gap = ({
    'Time' : ['8:03:00','8:17:00','8:20:00','8:28:00','8:35:00','08:40:00','08:42:00','08:45:00','08:50:00'],                 
    'Place' : ['House 1','House 2','House 3','House 4','House 1','House 1','House 2','House 1','House 3'],                 
    'Area' : ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'D', 'D', 'D'],     
    'On' : ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'], 
    'Person' : ['Person 1','Person 1','Person 1','Person 2','Person 3','Person 4','Person 3','Person 5','Person 6'],   
    }),
different_times = ({
    'Time' : ['8:03:00','8:17:00','8:20:00','8:28:00','8:35:00','08:40:00','09:42:00','09:45:00','09:50:00'],                 
    'Place' : ['House 1','House 2','House 3','House 4','House 1','House 1','House 2','House 1','House 1'],                 
    'Area' : ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'D', 'E', 'E', 'F', 'G'],     
    'On' : ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'], 
    'Person' : ['Person 1','Person 1','Person 1','Person 2','Person 3','Person 4','Person 3','Person 5','Person 6'],   
    })
)

expectedPeoples = dict(
    example1 = [1,1,1,2,3,2,3,2,3],
    example2 = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
    long_repeats = [1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,2],
    many_repeats = [1,1,1,2,2,3,3,2,3],
    large_gap = [1,1,1,2,3,3,2,2,3],
    different_times = [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3],
)

for name,d in ds.items():
    df = pd.DataFrame(d)
    expected = ['Person %d' % i for i in expectedPeoples[name]]
    ap = allocatePeople(df)

    print(name, ap, sep='\n', end='\n\n')
    np.testing.assert_array_equal(ap['Person'], expected)
```

The `assert_array_equal` statements pass, and the output matches OP's expected output:

```
example1
       Time    Place Area On    Person
0   8:03:00  House 1    A  1  Person 1
1   8:17:00  House 2    B  2  Person 1
2   8:20:00  House 3    C  3  Person 1
3   8:28:00  House 4    D  4  Person 2
4   8:35:00  House 5    E  5  Person 3
5  08:40:00  House 1    D  6  Person 2
6  08:42:00  House 2    E  7  Person 3
7  08:45:00  House 3    F  8  Person 2
8  08:50:00  House 2    G  9  Person 3

example2
      Time    Place Area On    Person
0  8:03:00  House 1    X  1  Person 1
1  8:17:00  House 2    X  2  Person 1
2  8:20:00  House 3    X  3  Person 1
3  8:28:00  House 1    X  3  Person 1
4  8:35:00  House 2    X  3  Person 1
5  8:40:00  House 3    X  3  Person 1
6  8:42:00  House 1    X  3  Person 1
7  8:45:00  House 2    X  3  Person 1
8  8:50:00  House 3    X  3  Person 1
```

The output for my test cases matches my expectations as well:

```
long_repeats
      Time    Place Area    Person On
0  8:03:00  House 1    A  Person 1  1
1  8:17:00  House 2    A  Person 1  2
2  8:20:00  House 3    A  Person 1  3
3  8:25:00  House 4    A  Person 2  4
4  8:30:00  House 1    B  Person 2  5
5  8:31:00  House 1    C  Person 3  6
6  8:35:00  House 2    C  Person 3  7
7  8:45:00  House 3    C  Person 3  8
8  8:50:00  House 2    B  Person 2  9

many_repeats
       Time    Place Area On    Person
0   8:03:00  House 1    A  1  Person 1
1   8:17:00  House 2    B  2  Person 1
2   8:20:00  House 3    C  3  Person 1
3   8:28:00  House 4    D  4  Person 2
4   8:35:00  House 1    D  5  Person 2
5  08:40:00  House 1    E  6  Person 3
6  08:42:00  House 2    E  7  Person 3
7  08:45:00  House 1    F  8  Person 2
8  08:50:00  House 2    F  9  Person 3

large_gap
       Time    Place Area On    Person
0   8:03:00  House 1    A  1  Person 1
1   8:17:00  House 2    B  2  Person 1
2   8:20:00  House 3    C  3  Person 1
3   8:28:00  House 4    D  4  Person 2
4   8:35:00  House 1    E  5  Person 3
5  08:40:00  House 1    F  6  Person 3
6  08:42:00  House 2    D  7  Person 2
7  08:45:00  House 1    D  8  Person 2
8  08:50:00  House 3    D  9  Person 3

different_times
       Time    Place Area On    Person
0   8:03:00  House 1    A  1  Person 1
1   8:17:00  House 2    B  2  Person 1
2   8:20:00  House 3    C  3  Person 1
3   8:28:00  House 4    D  4  Person 2
4   8:35:00  House 1    D  5  Person 2
5  08:40:00  House 1    E  6  Person 2
6  09:42:00  House 2    E  7  Person 3
7  09:45:00  House 1    F  8  Person 3
8  09:50:00  House 1    G  9  Person 3
```

Let me know if it does everything you wanted, or if it still needs some tweaks. I think everyone is eager to see you fulfill your vision.

Comment: @PeterJames123 As a point of clarification, if the areas in the input were `['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'D', 'F', 'D', 'G']`, should the order of the people in the output be `[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]` or `[1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3]`?

Comment: thank you for attempting this. I understand it's a difficult one. If they were within an hour of each other it would be `[1,1,1,2,3,2,3,2,3]`. The first `3` items in `[Area]` would be grouped first, all the `D's` would be grouped second, and the _leftovers_ would be grouped third.

Comment: in regards to your code it works on a few iterations but it seems to be assigning too few individuals for the amount of unique values occurring. I'll attach another example at the bottom of the question. Thank you for trying this again.

Comment: @PeterJames123 I posted a second version with an algorithm that more closely matches your idea of looking ahead an hour to see if someone should stay where they are (see `holdSieve` in the `getAssignedPeople ` function). Let me know if this one is good. If not, post more more example input/output data and we'll iterate again.

Comment: It's looking really close @tel! I'm liking the look of this. Just posted a new iteration. The total amount of individuals assigned is correct. Just need to refine the allocation of Area

Comment: @PeterJames123 I updated the code again to handle the case of runs of the same area, like the `C`s in your new second example.

Comment: Thanks @tel. You've given me a massive start on this. I just need to work out duplicate values and I think it's nearly there. More than happy to award the bounty for your input.

Comment: @PeterJames123 Much obliged, and happy to help. What exactly do you mean here by "duplicate values"?

Comment: @PeterJames123 Also, I updated the code to be more robust in finding repeated areas, and I added a couple of my own test cases (let me know if they match what you want). I added an explicit time check, so now it doesn't matter how far apart two repeated areas are in the dataframe, so long as they're less than an hour apart in time.

Comment: Thanks @tel. Can you provide a brief description on each. Do you have a preference? I've also added what I think will be the final 'test'. I've just added duplicate values.

Comment: @PeterJames123 Let me see if I understand: you want the first person to be able to take on an infinite number of jobs if there's a pattern of areas like `['a', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x',...]` or `['x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x',...]`? Is that intended to be a behavior that's unique to just the first person?

Comment: No sorry. There are only 3 `unqiue` values. `X` is the `Area` and `House 1,2,3`. They just repeat or are dupliacted. So they should be assigned to the same individual. Does that make sense?

Comment: There aren't 9 unique values. There's three, so they should all be assigned to the same individual.

Comment: @PeterJames123 I've fixed this answer so that all unique `(place, area)` pairs will be assigned to a single person, by way of the `assignedPlaces` dict. There's no easy fix for the other answer, so use this one.

Comment: Thanks mate. This is fantastic. I appreciate your effort with this.

Comment: I'm just having trouble with one issue. I posted it as another question but linked it to this question.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54101445/re-assign-unique-values-pandas-dataframe

Answer (score 1):

Ok, before we delve into the logic of the problem it is worthwhile to do some housekeeping to tidy-up the data and bring it into a more useful format:

```
#Create table of unique people
unique_people = df[['Person']].drop_duplicates().sort_values(['Person']).reset_index(drop=True)

#Reformat time column
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'])
```

Now, getting to the logic of the problem, it is useful to break the problem down in to stages.  Firstly, we will want to create individual jobs (with job numbers) based on the 'Area' and the time between them. i.e. jobs in the same area, within an hour can share the same job number.

```
#Assign jobs
df= df.sort_values(['Area','Time']).reset_index(drop=True)
df['Job no'] = 0
current_job = 1   
df.loc[0,'Job no'] = current_job
for i in range(rows-1):
    prev_row = df.loc[i]
    row = df.loc[i+1]
    time_diff = (row['Time'] - prev_row['Time']).seconds //3600
    if (row['Area'] == prev_row['Area'])  & (time_diff == 0):
        pass
    else:
        current_job +=1
    df.loc[i+1,'Job no'] = current_job
```

With this step now out of the way, it is a simple matter of assigning 'Persons' to individual jobs:

```
df= df.sort_values(['Job no']).reset_index(drop=True)
df['Person'] = ""
df_groups = df.groupby('Job no')
for group in df_groups:
    group_size = group[1].count()['Time']
    for person_idx in range(len(unique_people)):
        person = unique_people.loc[person_idx]['Person']
        person_count = df[df['Person']==person]['Person'].count()
        if group_size <= (3-person_count):
            idx = group[1].index.values
            df.loc[idx,'Person'] = person
            break
```

And finally,

```
df= df.sort_values(['Time']).reset_index(drop=True)
print(df)
```

I've attempted to code this in a way that is easier to unpick, so there may well be efficiencies to be made here.  The aim however was to set out the logic used.

This code gives the expected results on both data sets, so I hope it answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

In writing my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53246979/425458), I slowly came around to the idea that the OP's algorithm might be easier to implement with an approach that focuses on the jobs (which can be different), instead of the people (which are all the same). Here's a solution that uses the job-centric approach:

```
from collections import Counter
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def assignJob(job, assignedix, areasPerPerson):
    for i in range(len(assignedix)):
        if (areasPerPerson - len(assignedix[i])) >= len(job):
            assignedix[i].extend(job)
            return True
    else:
        return False

def allocatePeople(df, areasPerPerson=3):
    areas = df['Area'].values
    times = pd.to_datetime(df['Time']).values
    peopleUniq = df['Person'].unique()
    npeople = int(np.ceil(areas.size / float(areasPerPerson)))

    # search for repeated areas. Mark them if the next repeat occurs within an hour
    ixrep = np.argmax(np.triu(areas.reshape(-1, 1)==areas, k=1), axis=1)
    holds = np.zeros(areas.size, dtype=bool)
    holds[ixrep.nonzero()] = (times[ixrep[ixrep.nonzero()]] - times[ixrep.nonzero()]) < np.timedelta64(1, 'h')

    jobs =[]
    _jobdict = {}
    for i,(area,hold) in enumerate(zip(areas, holds)):
        if hold:
            _jobdict[area] = job = _jobdict.get(area, []) + [i]
            if len(job)==areasPerPerson:
                jobs.append(_jobdict.pop(area))
        elif area in _jobdict:
            jobs.append(_jobdict.pop(area) + [i])
        else:
            jobs.append([i])
    jobs.sort()

    assignedix = [[] for i in range(npeople)]
    for job in jobs:
        if not assignJob(job, assignedix, areasPerPerson):
            # break the job up and try again
            for subjob in ([sj] for sj in job):
                assignJob(subjob, assignedix, areasPerPerson)

    df = df.copy()
    for i,aix in enumerate(assignedix):
        df.loc[aix, 'Person'] = peopleUniq[i]
    return df
```

This version of `allocatePeople` has also been extensively tested and passes all of the same checks described in my other answer.

It does have more looping than my other solution, so it is likely to be slightly less efficient (though it'll only matter if your dataframe is very large, say `1e6` rows and up). On the other hand, it is somewhat shorter and, I think, more straightforward and easy to understand.